# Creating vector (with lines/polygons) from raster based on paper map in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, convert, image, vectorization

For a task I have several maps created with GIS that look like the following:

[image: Map view]

I am mainly interested in the colored zones that aren't roads (red) or rivers (blue) and would like to turn these into vectors for further spatial analysis. The extraction of this by a simple Raster to Vectors gives me incomplete lines/polygons because the edges of these zones aren't sufficiently sharp.

I have tried some approaches using reclassify values (with SAGA) to clean up the edges somewhat, edge detection using the Orfeo Toolbox, and raster calculator to make the non-white values stronger, but this doesn't seem to lead to sharper edges. Because these zones have a lot of edges, manual digitizing of the edges would be too time-consuming.

Are there any ways to automatize this process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not automatization (strictly speaking), but one good helper tool would be [Gimp Selection Feature](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/gimpselectionfeature_plugin/) plugin.

It enables us to access `Fuzzy selection tool` of Gimp 2.10, and returns a polygon layer taken from the area you have chosen.

[image]

When I tested it on your posted image, `Threshold` value set at 60.0 was good at differentiating the blue river and surrounding green area (it depends on your CRS, of course).

Comment: This seems to work for this problem, although I've had to adjust the threshold value a bit down (to 20) to get the lighter colored pink zones separated from the white background. Thanks!